# Facebook share link with custom text

Tags: hyperlink, facebook-javascript-sdk

How can I share a simple text on **facebook**, without any link? just a simple text.

I tried the `http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100` API, but that works only when sharing a link.
I tried the `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?` but I just could not manage it.

http://plnkr.co/edit/i7VmkZsb1rNqeEvmYyo6?p=preview

```
<a href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100
&p[title]=Title that I want to share' target='_blank' >
facebook sharer api
</a>
<br />
<a href='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
app_id=145634995501895&caption=Title that I want to share' target='_blank' >
facebook feed api
</a>
```

**EDIT**

It appears that I can't open a share box with my own custom text.

In the plunker above,
facebook share box fill 'http://run.plnkr.co/pYfbydYpZQfB5I3r/' in the share text.
How do I open the share box without any values?

Answer (score 10):

First of all, sharer.php only takes the URL as parameter, it reads the [Open Graph tags](http://ogp.me/) directly from the URL and you can't dynamically set anything. It is meant to share an URL, not just a message - and the message must be written by the user.

That being said, prefilling the message parameter is not allowed, not in any way:

> Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy

There is only one way to prefill the message, and that is by authorizing a User with the `publish_actions` permission and using [/me/feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed) to post a message. But `publish_actions` has to get approved by Facebook before you go public with an App - and even for that you have to present a possibility for the User to fill the message on his own. It always must be 100% User generated, without any prefilling. So you would never get through the review process, i am afraid.

More information about sharing on Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing

Answer (score -1):

Apart from the publish_action permissions, you'll need to add the **link** parameter while using the Facebook's feed dialogue. If you aren't using the **link** parameter, then you won't be able to share via feed dialogue.

Hope this helps..

Comment: you really don´t need any permission for the sharer.php or the feed dialog...sorry, but this answer is completely wrong and misleading.